# List of lists in sdk for smartglass

Tags: sony, sony-smarteyeglass

The examples contain a well working example of lists of items called `AdvancedLayout`.
It has a list of items and details for each item.
My question is whether it is possible or if Sony has an example project for list of lists? When you select an item of top level list you would go to another list belonging to this selected item and further to detail item for the sublist-item that you selected.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to achieve this feature. Currently you need to implement it manually.

The same way, how you display the first level of Items Gallery, you display the second level of Items Gallery after `onListItemClick`. You need to track your position, and level and decide, if to display the second layer, or the detail view.

Keep in mind, you should make the user experience consistent by using `moveLowerLayer` and `moveUpperLayer` when moving in your UI hierarchy as it is shown in `onListItemClick` and `onKey` callbacks.